# I am trying to run Druid REPLACE Query but got following error in my java project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, druid

{"error":"Unknown exception","errorMessage":"Unexpected character ('_' (code 95)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries\n at [Source: (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInputOverHTTP); line: 1, column: 132]","errorClass":"com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException","host":null}

Passing the druid REPLACE Query as a string Object and got the error.

Answer (score 0):

QQ when you run the same SQL command in the Druid Console, does the SQL work OK?

- If it works in the console, that at least pins this down to the way that you're forming the [SQL to POST](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/api-reference/sql-ingestion-api#submit-a-query).
- If it doesn't work in the console, at least you know there there is a syntax issue with the [REPLACE](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/multi-stage-query/reference#replace).